# iOS In-App purchase inside Action Extension

Tags: ios, in-app

Is it possible to create Custom iOS Extension, probably of type Action 
https://developer.apple.com/app-extensions/

And inside its content purchase product using in-app purchase ?

Let say I have limited app, with extension functionality and I want to give them option to buy it, while they are still inside their app, using extension itself.